# Determinant of 3 points.

Tags: determinant

I have $P=(p_1,p_2)$ and $Q=(q_1,q_2$) two points in $\mathbb R^2$, $P\ne Q$, and $R=(r_1,r_2)$ another point. What means the following determinant?

$$\Delta (P, Q, R)=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        p_1 & q_1 & r_1 \\
        p_2 & q_2 & r_2 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: take one of the points, say $P$, to be the origin, i.e., $p_1 = p_2 = 0$ see what the determinant represents.

Answer (score 3):

That is twice the signed area of the triangle $\triangle PQR$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates) for some more details.

By "signed" I mean that the vertices must be taken in the counterclockwise direction to get the area. If taken clockwise, you get the negative of the area.

Comment: you mean signed area?

Comment: @abel: Yes, I was working on adding that to my answer when I saw your comment. Thanks for the reminder.